# Find the values for which positive integer $n$ makes $A=\sqrt{n(n+182)}$ a rational number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Find the values for which positive integer $n$ makes $A=\sqrt{n(n+182)}$ a rational number

I tried to solve it in the following way:

$n(n+182)=k^2$ where k is an integer

$n^2+182n=k^2$

$(k-n)(k+n)=182n$

From here I tried getting all the divisors of $182=2*91$ and try solving it using divisibility rules. However I did not succeed.

Could you please show me a clever and intuitive approach to solving the problem?

Comment: Hint:  Note that $(n+91)^2=a^2$ is, of course, a square  so if $n^2+182n=b^2$ is also a square then we must have $a^2-b^2=91^2$.  (The idea here is that it is hard for two squares to be near each  other, so search for a known square near the desired one).

Comment: Do you want $A$ an integer or just a rational number?

Comment: @lulu thank you very much, great hint

Comment: @J.W.Tanner A is rational

Comment: hint: 4 solutions (only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n^2+182n=k^2\implies (n+91)^2=k^2+91^2\implies (n+91)^2-k^2=91^2\implies$

$ (n+91+k)(n+91-k)=7\times7\times13\times13.$

Can you solve $(n+91-k,n+91+k)=(7,7\times13\times13)$ or $(13,7\times7\times13)$

or $(7\times13,7\times13)$ or $(7\times7,13\times13)$?

Comment: Note that $(n+91-k,n+91+k)=(7\times13,7\times13)$ would imply $n=k=0$, which was excluded by OP